# How can I Add images dynamically through Camera or Gallery?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-gallery

I am making an Android Application where i am allowing user to click the picture through camera or add the Images through Gallery.

Only 5 images are allowed to be added in the image view . How i can add image view dynamically in the activity at the run time.

how to delete and re position the images present in the activity.

As there are 5 images so when i am deleting the 2nd image then the 3rd , 4th and 5th images should be re position to 2nd , 3rd and 4th position and it should allow me to add 5th image.

Can Anyone help me with the Source code .

This is my Code :

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_FIRST_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_SECOND_IMAGE = 101;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_THIRD_IMAGE = 102;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_FOURTH_IMAGE = 103;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_FIFTH_IMAGE = 104;
    private static final int PICK_PICTURE_FIRST_IMAGE = 105;
    private static final int PICK_PICTURE_SECOND_IMAGE = 106;
    private static final int PICK_PICTURE_THIRD_IMAGE = 107;
    private static final int PICK_PICTURE_FOURTH_IMAGE = 108;
    private static final int PICK_PICTURE_FIFTH_IMAGE = 109;
    Boolean imageclick_1 = false, imageclick_2 = false, imageclick_3 = false, imageclick_4 = false, imageclick_5 = false;
    TextView textview_imagename1, textview_imagename2, textview_imagename3, textview_imagename4, textview_imagename5;
ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView5;
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
 imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
 imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
        imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);
 imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview4);
        imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);
 imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview5);
        imageView5.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_PICTURE_FIRST_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage1 = data.getData();
                    String s1 = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage1);
                    try {
                        images1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView1.setImageURI(selectedImage1);
                    String name1 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    textview_imagename1.setText(name1);
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_1 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case PICK_PICTURE_SECOND_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage2 = data.getData();
                    String s2 = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage2);
                    try {
                        images2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView2.setImageURI(selectedImage2);
                    String name2 = s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    textview_imagename2.setText(name2);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_2 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case PICK_PICTURE_THIRD_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage3 = data.getData();
                    String s3 = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage3);
                    try {
                        images3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage3);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView3.setImageURI(selectedImage3);
                    String name3 = s3.substring(s3.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    textview_imagename3.setText(name3);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_3 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case PICK_PICTURE_FOURTH_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage4 = data.getData();
                    String s4 = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage4);
                    try {
                        images4 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage4);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView4.setImageURI(selectedImage4);
                    String name4 = s4.substring(s4.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    textview_imagename4.setText(name4);
                    imageView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_4 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case PICK_PICTURE_FIFTH_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage5 = data.getData();
                    String s5 = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage5);
                    try {
                        images5 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage5);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageView5.setImageURI(selectedImage5);
                    String name5 = s5.substring(s5.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    textview_imagename5.setText(name5);
                    imageclick_5 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_FIRST_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo1);
                    SaveImage(photo1);
                    textview_imagename1.setText(fname);
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_1 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_SECOND_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(photo2);
                    SaveImage(photo2);
                    textview_imagename2.setText(fname);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_2 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_THIRD_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo3 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView3.setImageBitmap(photo3);
                    SaveImage(photo3);
                    textview_imagename3.setText(fname);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_3 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_FOURTH_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo4 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView4.setImageBitmap(photo4);
                    SaveImage(photo4);
                    textview_imagename4.setText(fname);
                    imageView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageclick_4 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_FIFTH_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo5 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView5.setImageBitmap(photo5);
                    SaveImage(photo5);
                    textview_imagename5.setText(fname);
                    imageclick_5 = true;
                    deletebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        fname = "Image-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageview1:
                if (imageclick_1) {
                    fullimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    fullimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    final String[] Items = {"Click Pic", "Pick Pic", "Cancel"};
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
                    builder.setItems(Items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                isdialogset = "CAMERA";
                                if (imageView1.getDrawable() == null) {
                                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST_FIRST_IMAGE);
                                }
                            } else if (i == 1) {
                                isdialogset = "GALLERY";
                                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//                                pickPhoto.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)))
                                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_FIRST_IMAGE);
                            } else {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imageview2:
                if (imageclick_2) {
                    fullimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    fullimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("CAMERA") && imageView2.getDrawable() == null) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST_SECOND_IMAGE);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("GALLERY")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_SECOND_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imageview3:
                if (imageclick_3) {
                    fullimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView3.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    fullimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("CAMERA") && imageView3.getDrawable() == null) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST_THIRD_IMAGE);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("GALLERY")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_THIRD_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imageview4:
                if (imageclick_4) {
                    fullimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView4.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    fullimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("CAMERA") && imageView4.getDrawable() == null) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST_FOURTH_IMAGE);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("GALLERY")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_FOURTH_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imageview5:
                if (imageclick_5) {
                    fullimageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView5.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    fullimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("CAMERA") && imageView5.getDrawable() == null) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST_FIFTH_IMAGE);
                } else if (isdialogset.equals("GALLERY")) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, PICK_PICTURE_FIFTH_IMAGE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code, please. Code

Comment: please Check the Edit ... sorry for the delay

Comment: please rather the click on down arrow ... try to understand my problem and help if u can ... if u cant dont down arrow my question

Comment: If i am right you want to create imageview dynamically.

Comment: yes .... I want to create Imageview dynamically ... only 5 imageview should be there ,,.. and want to add delete functionality ... If deleted the position should be changed ....

Comment: @Abhijit I think it's because you've missed quite a few rules/guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Maybe start by shortening your code down to what ever is giving you the issue, and explaining to us why you can't solve your problem

Comment: my Code is different from what i want to ask .. its just what i have done so far ,, now i want to add imageview dynamically to the activity ...

Comment: if i want to delete the image which is in imageview then the position should be changed

Comment: @AbhijitPatil please try my answer as your need.Best of luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create ImageView dynamically like this :

```
 container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            ImageView newimageview = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            newimageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.panama_app_logo);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
            newimageview.setLayoutParams(params);
            container.addView(newimageview);
        }
```

Comment: Thank You @DK Thakur ... I will Try it to solve from using this method

Comment: you can remove imageview by using  view.removeViewAt(index);

Comment: `RelativeLayout dynamicRelative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicRelative);``int numberofimages = 4;`
`for (int j = 0; j < numberofimages; j++){
`Intent takePicture = new `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
`startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST); `newimageview = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);                                 dynamicRelative.setLayoutParams(new `ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`newimageview.setMaxHeight(50);`newimageview.setMaxWidth(50);
`dynamicRelative.addView(newimageview);

Comment: @DK Thakur Can u please check what is wrong with this code ... it is only showing one image

Comment: it is adding all but showing you only one because you are using RelativeLayout.If You use LinearLayout instead you can see all of your images added to view.

Comment: You can do this with RelativeLayout but you have to create relation b/w imageview dynamically.

Comment: @DK Thakur Sir .. The Loop is working But the application is getting terminated after clicking the images for 5 times...

Comment: `case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photos = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    newimageview.setImageBitmap(photos);
                    SaveImage(photos);
            }
                break;
            case PICK_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
try {NewImages = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);} catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}newimageview.setImageURI(selectedImage);}break;`

Comment: Dude i am here to give you hint,i can not code for you.You have to do this.

Comment: Ok Sir .. Thank You So much For ur help Appreciated for your time